# Различие методов call / apply в javascript?

Tags: javascript

Вызов `func.call(context, a,b...)` – то же, что обычный вызов `func(a, b...)`, но с явно указанным ***this(=context)***;
Метод **apply** работает так же как и метод **call**, с той разницей, что в него мы передаем не *контекст + строковые аргументы*, а *контекст + массив*

Я попробовал создать пример, который бы объяснил мне работу функции apply

```
var playList = {
  title: "favorite songs"   
}
var songs = [];
function makePlayList() {
  console.log(this.title+":");
  for (var i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    console.log((i+1)+": "+songs[i]);
  }
}

songs.push("Muse - Resistance");
songs.push("Tame Impala - Let It Happen");
songs.push("MGMT – Alien Days");

makePlayList.apply(playList,songs);
```

Но затем я попробовал строку

```
makePlayList.apply(playList,songs);
```

И понял, что я не понял в чем же суть метода apply,
помогите пожалуйста разъясните ситуацию на моем примере

Comment: метод apply нужен, когда ты не знаешь сколько параметров нужно будет передать в функцию

Answer (score 0):

Приветствую

```
someFunc.apply(ctx, [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
someFunc.call(ctx, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Вот и всё разница :)

В вашем примере ни call ни apply не нужны, так как ни аргументов у функции нет, ни контекст не используется. С приходом es6, манипуляции с this по большей части закончены.

В es6 массив в качестве аргументов можно передать через деструкцию:

```
const args = [arg1, arg2, arg3];
someFunc(...args);
// = someFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Также внутри функции, у которой есть контекст, всегда можно выяснить аргументы запросив `arguments` (даже если у функции явно аргументы не указаны)

Comment: Спасибо! хорошо, а можно ли пример использования функции apply, где контест будет важен  - я нахожу примеры, где контекст не имеет значения.

Comment: как же контекст не используется, если выводится `this.title`?

Comment: Да по контектом и поразумевается чему равняется this внутри функции. Примеры.. во многих библиотеках идёт расчёт на то, что в наших обработчиках this будет предоставлять тот или иной фунционал. Это работает за счёт того, что наши обработчики вызываются через call, apply или предварительный bind. Вот пример - исходник jquery https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/trigger.js

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko, я не понял к чему твой комментарий. Ты в ответе говоришь, что в примере не используется контекст, хотя он там используется

Comment: Да, я пропустил this.title, соррян

Comment: не отошёл с праздника

Comment: мне кажется все